# Node version managing strategy with Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, nvm

I am using NVM to manage my versions of NodeJS.  I am trying to integrate it with Maven in a Jenkins job.  The following script is executed before Maven runs.  I don't think there is a way to pass in the NodeJS installation directory to Maven as an option argument.  I believe `nvm use` exports the NodeJS installation directory to `PATH`, but I could be wrong.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
source /mounts/dev/jenkins/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm alias default node
nvm use --delete-prefix v4.2.0 --silent
```

The reason why Maven needs NodeJS is because of the `yeoman-maven-plugin`, which, by default, uses the globally installed version of NodeJS.  I know that there is a NodeJS plugin for Jenkins that works, but I don't think using that is optimal.

I think it's possible to integrate NVM into a Jenkins Maven job, but I may be going about it the wrong way.  Does anyone have any ideas on a different NVM approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to integrate NVM with Maven, we decided to abandon the `yeoman-maven-plugin`, and instead went with the `frontend-maven-plugin`.  The `frontend-maven-plugin` allows for local Node and NPM installations, along with other build tools like Gulp and Grunt.  The only change that needed to be made was to the `pom.xml`.  Plus, there is no more need for additional scripting in Jenkins.

**Usage example for installing Node and NPM**

```
<plugin>
  ...
  <execution>
      <!-- optional: you don't really need execution ids,
      but it looks nice in your build log. -->
      <id>install node and npm</id>
      <goals>
          <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
      </goals>
      <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
  </execution>
  <configuration>
      <nodeVersion>v0.10.18</nodeVersion>
      <npmVersion>1.3.8</npmVersion>
      <!-- optional: where to download node and npm from. Defaults to https://nodejs.org/dist/ -->
      <downloadRoot>http://myproxy.example.org/nodejs/dist/</downloadRoot>
      <!-- optional: where to install node and npm. Defaults to the working directory -->
      <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

More information about the plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin).