# npm run-script build is detecting older version of node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, maven, npm

I am trying to build my Angular project after upgrading from node 12 and angular 10 to node 16 and angular 13.

When I run `mvn clean install` it fails with this error

```
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ui ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:install-node-and-npm (install-npm) @ ui ---
[INFO] Node v16.13.1 is already installed.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:npm (npm-install --production) @ ui ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install -loglevel error' in C:\...\tbsis\UI
[INFO]
[INFO] up to date in 45s
[INFO]
[INFO] 104 packages are looking for funding
[INFO]   run `npm fund` for details
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:npm (npm-build) @ ui ---
[INFO] Running 'npm run-script build -- --output-hashing all' in C:\...\tbsis\UI
[INFO]
[INFO] > client@0.0.0 build
[INFO] > ng build  "--output-hashing" "all"
[INFO]
[ERROR] Node.js version v10.24.1 detected.
[ERROR] The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v12.20, v14.15, or v16.10.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
[ERROR]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  46.906 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-02T16:03:03-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:npm (npm-build) on project ui: Failed to run task: 'npm run-script build -- --output-hashing all' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 3 (Exit value: 3) -> [Help 1]
```

I have completely uninstalled node.js and npm and reinstalled npm@8.3.2 and node@16.13.1.

I cleared all the system and account environment variables for node and npm and added them back after a fresh installation.

--- tech stack

```
C:\...\tbsis\UI>node -v
v16.13.1

C:\...\tbsis\UI>npm -v
8.3.2

C:\...\tbsis\UI>ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 13.1.2
Node: 16.13.1
Package Manager: npm 8.3.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.2.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1302.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.2.1
@angular-devkit/core            13.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.2.1
@angular/cli                    13.1.2
@schematics/angular             13.1.2
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.5.5
```

--- build portion of pom.xml

```
<build>
        <resources>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webXml>src/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    -->
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>target/classes/static</directory>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/WEB-INF/</directory>
                            <!--
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <include>jboss-web.xml</include>
                            -->
                            <targetPath>/WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v16.13.1</nodeVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>

                    <execution>
                         <id>install-npm</id>
                         <goals>
                             <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                         </goals>
                     </execution>
                    <execution>
                         <id>npm-install --production</id>
                         <goals>
                             <goal>npm</goal>
                         </goals>
                         <configuration>
                             <arguments>install  -loglevel error</arguments>
                         </configuration>

                     </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm-build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run-script build -- --output-hashing all</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>grunt webxml</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>grunt</goal>

                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>webxml</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I'm not sure what to do anymore, I even commented out the `install-node-and-npm` goal and manually copied my node folder to the project directory. Both of which are listed as version 16.13.1.

I am at a loss where maven is detecting this older version from. Any ideas?

Comment: And you already checked things like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646391/wrong-node-js-version-detected and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305751/node-version-managing-strategy-with-maven ?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes. My <nodeVersion></nodeVersion> tags are set correctly.

Comment: Reading through https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin it seems you're not following their instructions, though. If you _have_ node installed, you the `exec-maven-plugin`, not `frontend-maven-plugin`. And if you want `frontend-maven-plugin`, your XML does not seem to match what the the readme says it should look like.

Comment: From what I understand ```frontend-maven-plugin``` is intended to install node and npm within the project directory, which it is indeed doing within my project. I was showing my tech stack which is the matching node version to make it clear that the node version it is detecting is not coming from my system. I think I still need ```frontend-maven-plugin```